# Auto load view composer file

Tags: view, laravel-5, composer-php, autoload

I just watched the Laracast video on View Composers.

Everything is working but there is one last part of the video that I am clueless about.

I have the following code in my `routes.php`:

```php
View::composer('layouts.partials.sidebar', 'App\Composers\SidebarComposer');
```

At the end of the video it explains that this can be removed from the routes file. In the `starts/global.php` file he adds the following code:

```php
require app_path() . 'composers.php';
```

I don't have the `starts/global.php` file so what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: The Laracast you were watching was for Laravel 4 but you are using Laravel 5. The structure how things are organized changed completely in some parts in L5. Make sure you use a Laravel 5 how to. Not everything that was good in L4 is still good in L5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a service provider for composers and put your view composers in `App\Http\ViewComposers` (you are free to put it anywhere else). Don't forget to register this service provider to the `providers` array in the `config/app.php`.

See this example below:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using class based composers...
        view()->composer(
            'profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
        );

        // Using Closure based composers...
        view()->composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

For more information see the official Laravel 5 documentation -> [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank You.